# Can't get audio chat flutter app to run on iOS - 'AgoraRtcKit/AgoraRtcEngineKit.h' file not found

Tags: flutter, flutter-dependencies, agora.io

I am trying to run the flutter code from the following repository

https://github.com/perpetio/clubhouse

It succesfully installs and loads on Android (still working on the firebase authentication)

Unfortunately, on iOS (both simulator and device) I get the error message: " 'AgoraRtcKit/AgoraRtcEngineKit.h' file not found" which itself is thrown by the AgoraRtcEngineKit.h file during import

```
#import <AgoraRtcKit/AgoraRtcEngineKit.h>
```

Tried the scarce available solutions (mostly in the context of react-native) however still not working..

Many thanks in advance for your help

Answer (score 0):

Did you make sure to add the iOS permissions? https://pub.dev/packages/agora_rtc_engine#ios

If you did, try this as well: https://pub.dev/packages/agora_rtc_engine#ios-video-cant-show-android-works-fine